# Having troubles carrying across ints to move a object

Tags: java

I'm making my first java application and for the game play I'm trying to make a green brick move to another green brick. I want it to move across the x axis then down the y axis. The problem I'm running in to is I change the object's x value  in a function that is called when the mouse is clicked but the object it self never moves even though the a variable holding it's x position does change.

```
public class GameState {

//Players variables
private int xPos = 50;
private int yPos = 50;

public void update() {

}
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 360);
    Entitys.playerEntity(g, xPos, yPos, TAGS.CONTROLLABLE);
    Entitys.walkingBoxEntity(g, 150, 150, TAGS.CLICKABLE);
}

public void mouseClicked(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
    if (mouseX > 150 && mouseX < 200) {
        if (mouseY > 150 && mouseY < 200) {
            int destination = 150;
            int moveDistance = destination -= xPos;
            if (moveDistance > 0) {
                for (int dM = 0; dM < moveDistance; dM++) {
                    xPos++;
                    System.out.println(xPos);
                }
            } else {
                for (int dM = 0; dM > moveDistance; dM--) {
                    xPos--;
                    System.out.println(xPos);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

The variable holding the players entity x position is xPos. If I go in the update function and go xPos++ it does move across the screen. If I make a function that has the line of code and call it in the update function it does move. But when I try to do it in the mouseClicked function it does not move. If I print out the value of xPos it does change but the brick doesn't move. How come the brick moves outside of the clickedMouse function but not inside the function?

Comment: What framework are you using?  My guess: sounds like render isn't being called.  You probably need to trigger a render somehow when your state has changed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the render is being called, if I got xPos++ in the render the brick does move. I Just use a enum for the states if thats what you mean by framework. Are you suggesting I should call the render then change the state?

Comment: By framework I mean that nobody is calling render in the code you posted.  Where does render get called?  Do you call it or does something else?

Comment: Yea I have the game loop calling it

Comment: Figured it out!! Probably looking at the completely wrong way but I just made every function in the class static so I never have to make an instance of the class and it seemed to work